# How to update Item with one click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update Item that are stored in my DB with one click.
For example i have model called Car. It has attribute called "active" which is Boolean so could be 0 or 1 in DB. I want that users have a possibility to change this this attribute with one click for example from index page of their cars.  I know that it could be done if i would make this button like the whole form. But i think it is not the best solution and not right. Could i make it in any another way, maybe create special link_to or something like this?
As i understand it should send request to CarsController into update method, but how to do this without form?

Comment: Hint: Think javascript.

Comment: https://medium.com/@codenode/how-to-use-remote-true-to-make-ajax-calls-in-rails-3ecbed40869b Might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to use `link_to` with `remote: true`.
For example in your view:

```
link_to "Activate", car_path(@car.id), method: :post, remote: true
```

And in your controller method:

```
def active
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @car.update(active: true)
  render json: :ok
end
```

A complete guide present [here.](https://medium.com/@codenode/how-to-use-remote-true-to-make-ajax-calls-in-rails-3ecbed40869b)

Comment: Hmm... how this link would be connected with active method? I think in this case i should add something to my routes?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a route. Or if you already ran scaffolding then default routes will be there for you. Please go through the ruby on rails guides https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
If my answer helped you then please accept my answer. Thank you

Comment: I mean that link_to "Activate", car_path(@car.id), method: :post, remote: true would go to "Create" action, not to active action. Active action is not part of the :resources so even with scaffolding routes for it would not be created. Perhaps i need to add action: active after remote: true ?

Comment: @web-wolf it was just an example to get an understanding of how it will work. And yes you need to create a route and a method in your controller to achieve this. Please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: No, thank you, i understand now and have solved this problem. As i have simple Rails application, without using API and json, i get rid of the remore: true and render json

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you can use jquery ajax method with dataType as JSON.
And you can also use the same restful update method i.e without creating any new method.

View -
`<%= button_tag 'Activate', car_id: "22" , id: "activate_car"  %>`

Controller -

```
  def update
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.update(car_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :json: 'Successfully update' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def car_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:active)
  end
```

JS -

```
$(document).on("click", '#activate_car', function () {
  car_id = $(this).attr('car_id')
  $.ajax({
    url: "/cars/" + car_id,
    type: "PUT",
    data: {
      active: true
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but adding this answer for new rails developers

You simply need to use `link_to` with `remote: true`. If `link_to` throws routing error then use `button_to` instead
For example in your view:

```
button_to "Activate", car_path(@car.id), method: :patch, remote: true
```

And in your controller method:

```
def active
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @car.update(active: true)
  redirect_to cars_path(@cars), status: :see_other
end
```

And in your routes.rb :

```
resources :cars do
      member do
        patch :active
      end
    end
```